# Setting UIViewController as delegate of custom UIView within UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

So the title pretty much explains my issue.

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UITableView`. In all of the `UITableViewCells` there is a custom `UIButton`, but in just *one* of these, I want to set the `delegate` as the top level `UIViewController`. i.e tapping this button, triggers something to happen on the `UIViewController`

If I set the `delegate` on all the buttons, this works fine - but I don't want to set it on all the buttons. If I try and single out the cell that I want, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, the `delegate` always ends up being `nil`. If I step through, the delegate is being correctly set when the `tableView` is loading, but when I hit the button and step through what is happening, the delegate is nil.

Including some of my `tableView` code below. Left some bits out to make it faster to read. Is it possible that I'm being caught out by some reuse stuff, or?

//ViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = [self configureButtonCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];    
    return cell;
}


- (SLPButtonCell *)configureButtonCell:(SLPButtonCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{          
    NSDictionary *button = [self.buttons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.delegate = self;

    cell.indexPath = indexPath;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (button is type 1) {
        //do whatever
    }
    else if (button is type2) {
        [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
        cell.googleSsoButton.delegate = self;
    }
    else {

    //do whatever


    }
    return cell;

}

- (void)signInWasSuccessful
{
//success code happens here
}
- (void)signInWasUnsuccessful:(NSError *)error
{
//non success happens here
}
```

// Google SSO Button.h

```
@protocol GoogleSSOButtonDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)signInWasSuccessful;
- (void)signInWasUnsuccessful:(NSError *)error;

@end

@interface GoogleSSOButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<GoogleSSOButtonDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

//Google SSO Button.m

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (custom stuff works) {
       if ([_self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(signInWasSuccessful)]){
              [_self.delegate signInWasSuccessful];
       }

    }
    else {
      if ([_self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(signInWasUnsuccessful:)]){
              [_self.delegate signInWasUnsuccessful:error];

    }
  }
}
```

To give a full sequence of events:

1. User presses the Sign In Button - calling sign in and triggering the `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate`.
2. The button is also the `GIDSignInDelegate`, so when the sign in is complete, either succesfully, or unsuccesfully, it returns on the button
3. My implementation of the `GIDSignInDelegate` then triggers my custom `delegate`, which needs to trigger on the top level `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0):

To (dis)prove my theory, you'll need to post your custom delegate code. Can you add that to your question?

My guess though, is that you're confusing `cell.googleSsoButton.delegate` and `cell.delegate`:

```
- (SLPButtonCell *)configureButtonCell:(SLPButtonCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{          
    // here you set delegate for every cell:
    cell.delegate = self;

    // here you do your conditional
    else if (button is type2) {
        [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
        cell.googleSsoButton.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Also of note, `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate` is a shared instance/singleton - you can't set that conditionally, because it's always going to be set to `self` so long as your else statement is reached once. Suggest moving that into the controller's `viewDidLoad` and out of your table view delegates.

Comment: I've added the custom delegate code to my question. Regarding the uiDelegate, that if branch isn't guaranteed to be hit every time (The ViewController is reused in a couple of different places, configured by an API), so don't want to set it unnecessarily in the viewDidLoad

Comment: Well, thing is, it's a shared instance. That means every single time you set it, it's going to affect everywhere it's in use. I think you should re-think the logic around how that's implemented.

Comment: And where is your delegate written then? In your SLPButtonCell class? Or in whatever class googleSsoButton is?

Comment: I've added more detail on the delegate just now!